# Automatically populate errors for reactive form controls in Angular 2/4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have validation on both frontend and backend sides. Everything is ok with a frontend one, but I can not get to work the backend validation on frontend (manually mark controls as invalid based on backend validation).

The problem is in populating form controls with errors, looks like I cannot just make `this.formBuiltWithFormBuilder.setErrors()` and pass an object with errors to automatically populate all controls included in a form - as only form became invalid when all field statuses stay the same.

So currently I'm trying to do something like:

```
// Example of incoming formErrors:
// (it can also be nested for nested forms)
// {
//    phone: {
//      phoneNumberNoMatch: "The input does not match..."
//    }
// }

@Input() public formErrors: ValidationErrors;
public detailsForm: FormGroup;

public ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
}

public ngOnChanges() {
  this.updateFormErrors(this.formErrors);
}

private createForm(account: AccountInterface) {
  this.detailsForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

private updateFormErrors(errors: any) {
  if (this.detailsForm) {
    // Trying to populate included form controls with errors
    this.detailsForm.setErrors(errors);
  }
}
```

```

I also thought about walking through the errors object and applying errors manually for each control, but I think this solution is not an ideal as there may be nested forms.

So is it a way to automatically populate form controls with errors?

Comment: how form knows that errors belong to what control?

Comment: Have you looked into using [custom validation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation)?

Comment: Hey Julia, errors, that came from the backend have the same names as  form controls. @richards, hmm, it may have sense, but as I understand it will be necessary to bind custom validator to all form controls manually - I need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no built-in solution, so I've created a form helper class to populate errors. In theory it should also populate nested/array forms too, but I've tested it for only plain forms. Let me know if it doesn't ;)

It uses `lodash/map` method to walk through the errors object.

```
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray } from '@angular/forms';
import { map } from 'lodash';

export class FormHelper {
  public static POPULATE_FORM_GROUP_ERRORS(
    rootFormGroup: FormGroup,
    errors: any
  ) {
    map(rootFormGroup.controls, (control, name) => {
      if (control instanceof FormControl) {
        if (errors.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          control.setErrors(errors[name]);
        }
      }
      if (control instanceof FormGroup) {
        if (errors.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
          FormHelper.POPULATE_FORM_GROUP_ERRORS(control, errors[name]);
        }
      }
      if (control instanceof FormArray) {
        if (errors.hasOwnProperty(name) && errors[name] instanceof Array) {
          this.iterateOverFormArrayControl(control, errors[name]);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  private static iterateOverFormArrayControl(
    formArray: FormArray, 
    errors: any[]
  ) {
    errors.forEach((error: any, index: number) => {
      const arrayControl = formArray.at(index);
      if (arrayControl && arrayControl instanceof FormControl) {
        arrayControl.setErrors(error);
      }
      if (arrayControl && arrayControl instanceof FormGroup) {
        FormHelper.POPULATE_FORM_GROUP_ERRORS(arrayControl, error);
      }
      if (arrayControl && arrayControl instanceof FormArray && error instanceof Array) {
        FormHelper.iterateOverFormArrayControl(arrayControl, error);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

So now my form looks like:

```
// ... Somewhere at the top
import { FormHelper } from '@app/commons/FormHelper';
// ...

// Example of incoming formErrors:
// (it can also be nested for nested forms)
// {
//    phone: {
//      phoneNumberNoMatch: "The input does not match..."
//    }
// }

@Input() public formErrors: ValidationErrors;
public detailsForm: FormGroup;

public ngOnInit() {
  this.createForm();
}

public ngOnChanges() {
  this.updateFormErrors(this.formErrors);
}

private createForm(account: AccountInterface) {
  this.detailsForm = this.fb.group({
    firstName: ['', Validators.required],
    lastName: ['', Validators.required]
  });
}

private updateFormErrors(errors: any) {
  if (this.detailsForm) {
    // Populate included form controls with errors
   FormHelper.POPULATE_FORM_GROUP_ERRORS(this.detailsForm, errors);
  }
}
```